# save a pyspark dataframe inside a function

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to save a pyspark dataframe into a hdfs folder. this code is working fine outside the function but once i try to put it in a function, i am getting errors. Probably a case of how i am referencing the function arguments. Thanks for the help.

```
def save_file(df):

    start_time = time.time()

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("df") 
    hc.sql("create table hdfs_folder.{} as select * from {}".format(df,df))

    print("{} saved in hdfs_folder".format(df))

    print("**********************************")    
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

save_file(py_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to use string `df` instead of variable `df` as following:

```
def save_file(df):

    start_time = time.time()

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("df") 
    hc.sql("create table hdfs_folder.{} as select * from {}".format('df','df'))

    print("{} saved in hdfs_folder".format('df'))

    print("**********************************")    
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

save_file(py_df)
```

Edited - Using the variable name:

```
def save_file(df, name):

    start_time = time.time()

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("df") 
    hc.sql("create table hdfs_folder.{} as select * from {}".format(name,'df'))

    print("{} saved in hdfs_folder".format(name))

    print("**********************************")    
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

save_file(py_df, 'py_df')
```

Comment: thanks, but now it is naming the saved file as "df", i want the file to be named as function argument  i.e. "py_df", because i am calling save_file(py_df)

Comment: @spoonman, If you want to save the file with the "variable" name, then you need to pass the name as a string to the function as well.